# Looping in Firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to find a way to print/isolate each of the children in a part of the JSON data structure in Firebase. I am using swift and another post mentioned and verified this as the solution.

```
for child in snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("vets").children {
    print(child.key)
}
```

but this is not valid because it comes with this warning.

```
Ambiguous use of 'key'
```

how do you recommend I loop through the data? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("vets").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for child in snapshots {
                print("Child: ", child)
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: How do I print the children of those children?

Comment: Updated code to full block. Prints all children and values.

Comment: @Ryan, did that do what you needed?

Answer (score 1):

Just make an array of snapshot with keys and loop through it just like that if you want keys of "vets":

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("vets")

ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    for key in [snapshot.key] {
        print(key)
    }
}
```

However, if you want the keys of "vets" children then you can do it like this:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    guard let snapChildren = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    for (key, value) in snapChildren {
        print(key)
    }
}
```

If you need all key-value pairs of "vets" you may get them like this:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    guard let snapChildren = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    for snap in snapChildren {
        print(snap)
    }
}
```

Wanna print value for a certain key of vets children? Let's say you want to print a vet name:

```
ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    guard let snapChildren = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    for (key, value) in snapChildren {
        if key == "Name" {
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

***Note: 
This code will work assuming your path is Database.database().reference().child("vets") and that each vet entry has some kind of AutoID or UID which is our snapshot.key in the first example.***