# How do I get the child (different values) of a child in firebase SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the child of a child in firebase and retrieve information from it. But I can't just add `.child()` without any arguments inside as this gives an error.

[image: Firebase]

[image: Firebase 2]

I'm trying to retrieve the "present" but there will be a different child (Dates) where I will have to retrieve that.

I tried something like

```
        Database.database().reference().child("Attendance").child("Checkin").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print (snapshot)


        }
```

but that would print everything under the "Checkin".

As mentioned above I just need to retrieve the present from different dates (Child) if that makes sense. I'm still new to swift and firebase so any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `.child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child("BM050...").child("UC3F...").observeSingleEvent()`, and then loop over the snapshot?

Comment: How do i loop over the snapshot

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38023611/6792327